# Doing all possible arithemetic operations between 3 numbers

Tags: algorithm

Summary:

I have a set of 3 numbers, lets say (a,b,c). I want to perform all arithmetic operations (+,-.*,/) between these numbers and get the resultant values.

My idea is to generate subsets.

1] [(a,b), c]

2] [(a,c), b]

3] [(c,b), a]

Now within the set [(a,b),c], I will perform all operations between “a” and “b”, store them as “r1”,”r2”, “r3”..etc. Once that is done, I will perform all operations between “r1”, “r2”... and “c” to get the final result values.

Is this an optimal way to achieve my goal?

EDIT-1:

As an example, if i have numbers (1,2,3) then I want to do the following

1+2+3 =  6

1+2-3 = 0

1-2-3

1*2*3 = 6

and so on.

Basically, all possible arithmetic operations between the set of numbers.

Comment: Please clarify: What values do you want exactly? Suppose a = 5, b = 5 and c = 3. Do you want `a+b+c`, `a+c+b`, `b+a+c`, `b+c+a` etc. or only a subset of them?

Comment: @thiton , i have clarified the question, please refer to EDIT-1 in the main posting.

Comment: You might be asking for one of several things: (1) all syntactically different expressions regardless of whether they are mathematically equivalent; (2) all expressions that represent mathematically distinct operations, even if they happen to produce the same answer for given input values a, b, and c; (3) a set of expressions that produce distinct values for the given input. Which is it?

Comment: @TedHopp , All different expressions regardless of whether they are mathematically equivalent or not.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is simply NO. It is not optimal. For example you will calculate (a+b)+c and (a+c)+b but both of them have the same value.

Comment: @Seed Amiri, i didnt downvote your answer, i just upvoted it :).  Question --> What would be an optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: @bhavesh, because number of possible different valid statements is smaller than 48, you can try all of them in your code (sure is efficient but not programming challenge), but as I wrote this is just short answer, currently is my sleeping time, I'll think about your problem and if I got some elegant way I'll wrote it. Also is better to rephrase your question, one of a reason I wrote this answer is because remind you ask question clearly.

Comment: The number of possible different valid statements is larger than 48. For example, the pattern `[a+b+c, a+b-c, a+b*c, a+b/c]` makes up 24 possible statements because there are six permutations (i.e. (a=1,b=2,c-3), (a=1,b=3,c=2), etc.). Multiply that by 4 because the first operator can be +, -, *, or /. That gives 96 different valid statements. Granted, many of them are semantically identical, but they're syntactically different.

Comment: @JimMischel, that was simple mistake, I thought we have 4^2 different operation and 3! different permutation it will be 3*16 = 48 :) in fact it's 6*16 = 96. As I wrote it was my sleeping time, anyway it means number of different way in this case is small.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is basically sound, but incomplete. First, note that under the normal rules of arithmetic you will need to either include some parentheses in your output (to represent groupings such as [(a+b)*c]) or else accept that some combinations of operations will not be present in your final output.

Also, you will not be able to generate certain other combinations of arithmetic operations at all, such as "1*(2+3)". (This assumes that you want to consider "1*(2+3)" as distinct from "(2+3)*1". Lexically it certainly is.) For that, you will also need to include among the subsets, all groupings of the form [a, (b, c)]. If you include this second set of groupings, you will in essence be generating the parse trees of every possible expression. However, this creates a complication that others have noted in comments: "1+(2+3)" and "(1+2)+3" are identical once you remove the redundant parentheses.

There is also another problem if you allow for two (or all three) of a, b, and c to be equal. (For instance, if (a, b, c) = (1, 3, 3), then "1+3+3", among other things, will appear twice, once for [(a+b)+c] and once for [(a+c)+b]. If you allow for groupings like [a,(b,c)], then it will appear a total of four times once you eliminate the unnecessary parentheses.) If you want to allow for equality between a, b, and/or c, and yet avoid duplicate outputs, you will need to eliminate duplicates at some stage:

- generate all outputs and test for duplicates (by simple string comparison, for instance)
- generate all parse trees and test for duplicates there (not much different from the first, but avoids the work of generating the final output before discarding it)
- prune the collection of subsets before starting the process of inserting operators (probably the best)
- avoid generating duplicate subsets by a more sophisticated scheme of generation (which I can't think of off the top of my head)

Finally (I think), if you allow for the second set of groupings and also allow for duplicates among a, b, and c, then there are expressions such as "1 / (3 - 3)" that cannot be evaluated. (I don't think this comes up with the groupings [(a,b),c] unless you allow the input to include zero.) You'll have to decide what you want to do about them.